# How can I pass a parameter into the batch class?

Tags: batch, parameters

How can I pass a parameter into the batch class? How do I change the executeBatch to add a parameter? I need a parameter to make the query dynamic. The Status can be changed.

```
        Id bc = Database.executeBatch(new getBWS_Batch(), 2000);
```

**BATCH CLASS**

```
public class getBWS_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
    public String query = 'SELECT Id FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c like ' + Parameter;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CustomCC__c> records){
        List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS1_val__c) BWS1 WHERE Id = :records];       
        for (AggregateResult ar: groupedResults) {
            ACount_v2__c av2            = new ACount_v2__c();
            av2.BWS1_val__c             = (Decimal) ar.get('BWS1');
            av2.data__c                 = System.today();
            av2.Status__c               = Parameter;
            insert av2;
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){     
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can define a parametrized constructor.

```
    public getBWS_Batch(String Parameter){
        this.Parameter = Parameter;
    }
```

---

```
public class getBWS_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    public String  Parameter;
    public getBWS_Batch(){

    }

    public getBWS_Batch(String Parameter){
        this.Parameter = Parameter;
    }

    public String query = 'SELECT Id FROM CustomCC__c WHERE Status__c like ' + Parameter;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CustomCC__c> records){
        List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT sum(BWS1_val__c) BWS1 WHERE Id = :records];
        for (AggregateResult ar: groupedResults) {
            ACount_v2__c av2            = new ACount_v2__c();
            av2.BWS1_val__c             = (Decimal) ar.get('BWS1');
            av2.data__c                 = System.today();
            av2.Status__c               = Parameter;
            insert av2;
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
}
```

So you can execute it  `Id bc = Database.executeBatch(new getBWS_Batch('your parameter'), 2000);`